# Как скрыть меню поверх фрейма

Tags: css, iframe, видео, header

У меня на странице есть iframe с видео с YouTube, и есть фиксированный хедер, который при перемещении по странице скрывается и появляется. Когда открываю видео на весь экран, сверху появляется хедер поверх видео, как его убрать?

Comment: используйте z-index

Comment: Или я его неправильно использую, или он корректно не работает, для хедера стоит значение 1000, для фрейма 3000

Comment: Свойство z-index работает только для элементов у которых position задано как absolute, fixed или relative. Вы это учли?

Comment: Учил, вот и возник вопрос, а если не задано position, что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Задать его. Попробуйте для iframe задать position: relative